# Does MovieLens 100k dataset lack the validation set?

Tags: validation

The MovieLens 100k data set provides five pairs of training and test sets for 5-fold cross validation. However, I learnt that a validation set should be used prior to testing on the test set, in order to get the optimal parameter values.

I assume that in the original split, the five "test sets" are actually the validation sets. If that's true, then there are no "test set" which the model performance can be tested on. So shall I re-split the MovieLens data in order to perform a sound train-validate-test process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You actually have 2 options for the tests in the movielens set.

First option :
Users are split into 5 groups, and in each group is also split in a base group and a test group.
The base groups are here to "train" your algorithms, and the test groups to test. You have 5 different groups so you can do the learning and the testing process 5 times, and eventually have a statistical informations on various sets.

Second option :
Every user in the 100k set have 20 ratings. In the second case, you have two sets a and b.
Each user has 10 ratings on a and 10 ratings on b. You can therefore learn from the set a, and then try to guess and compare for the set b.

Of course, having the complete set, you can also set your own groups if you wants !